# Why is Java's "out/in" PrintStream field designed to be referenced directly rather than using a getter

Tags: java, field, getter, printstream

This is something I've always been curious about since my first "Hello World"

Why is Java's out PrintStream a static field that is designed to be used rather than making something like a "getOut()" method that would return the PrintStream. Everything I've learned about good coding practices screams that this is the best way to do things. Why doesn't Java do it?

Comment: Public variables aren't the end of the world if they're `final`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate reason is that the `System` streams predate the JavaBeans model with its `get/set/is` nomenclature, which was added in 1.1; the `System` streams go all the way back to 1.0, before even inner classes, so backwards compatibility demands continuity.

A related reason is that calls to getters can't be as efficiently inlined as direct field references, even if the methods are `final`, and since printing output is so common, it's likely that even today, those fields would be used directly.

Comment: Interfaces (like [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html)) existed in Java 1.0.

Comment: @VGR You're right; I was remembering all inner classes instead.